# IOS Segue proper use

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I have started learning ios. I come from a web development background.

I am getting a little confused when to use segue from the ViewController or from a specific button.

For example: if I have a `HomeViewController`, then I have a button "Agree terms" when I tap it, It will take me to `TermsViewController`. Should I create the segue from the "Agree terms" button or by selecting whole ViewController (from the topbar)? Which are the differences?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, you should be more specific with your question. Also, you are asking multiple questions in one, is better to be specific of one question and give details of it ir order for people to be with more information to help you.

Comment: Thanks @MagoNicolasPalacios I will try to be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to create a segue from the view controller itself.

You would then create an IBAction for the button on the view controller, and have the action call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];`

This is more or less exactly what creating the segue from a button does. If this is 100% all you need to do, that's perfectly acceptable. But this is a more maintainable solution, as it allows you to easily add additional functionality to buttons.  I.e., say your button requires you to save an object to a server. You want to save that object before you move away from the page, so you'd put the `performSegueWithIdentifier` call in the completion block of the save.

Additionally, creating the segue from the storyboard with an identifier allows you to use that segue for multiple buttons. For example, say you have a view controller with 4 buttons that all go to an information page relating to that button. You only need one "goToInfo" segue on your storyboard, but you can set up 4 individual IBActions for those buttons that do different set up, then prepare the view controller based on the data set up in the IBActions for the buttons. This will keep your storyboard a bit cleaner, because instead of needing 4 different segues that are all visible on the SB, you only have the 1.

tl;dr - creating the segue from the button is fine as long as that is 100% the only thing you need to do when pushing the button. If there is anything else that needs to happen in the background, it would be better to create the segue from the VC, and call it via its identifier after you complete the additional steps.

Edit - I suppose I've misled you slightly. One thing that you could do is override the method `-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`.  You set up an if / else if chain checking to see if segue.identifier is equal to the strings you set the identifier to, and you can perform various logic within those blocks that will get called even if you attach the segue directly to the button. The only problem with this is that it is a void function, and the segue will be performed after this regardless of any issues you may find with data entered on the page.

Now, I usually override this method anyway, so that I can pass data between VCs. This is where you would set the properties of `segue.destinationViewController`, after casting it to the ViewController class that you know it is.  I would not put any heavy lifting logic here, and certainly no server calls. Those are cases you would definitely want to set up an IBAction from the button that performs the logic / server call, and calls `performSegue` when you're done and know things worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

**from button**

It will call the segue you have assigned to it.

**from the viewController**

You MUST call   `performSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender: Any?)` yourself

Comment: Hi @Honey, thanks for your answer. One more thing, Can I call the segue from any ViewController or only from 2 which are related?

Comment: @Eduardo EVERY Segue that you create in storyboard has a `destinationViewcontroller` and a `sourceViewcontroller`. So your bound to them only. If you want to be able to segue into another viewController on the go, then you must do it programmatically without using segues and using `showViewcontroller` or `presentViewController`

Comment: @Eduardo `performSegueWithIdentifier` is an instance method, as opposed to a class method.  It checks for a segue with that identifier that originates from the View Controller you call it on., not any segue on the storyboard.

Comment: @Honey segues have the property `sourceViewController`

Comment: @JakeT. Thanks for your comment. Anything wrong in my answer? Or that was just a comment to Eduardo for better understanding?

Comment: @Honey just a correction of your original comment that said `originViewController` rather than `sourceViewController`. Your answer is correct.